# How to use a variable to set th:include value?

Tags: thymeleaf

To make this simple, let's assume we have a template html file(**test.htm**) like this:

```html
<div th:fragment="test">
    this is a test fragment
</div>
<div th:include=":: test"> <!-- we'll change this line later -->
    this is a placeholder
</div>
```

And the following controller is used to return test.htm:

```java
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView get(ModelAndView mav) {
        mav.setViewName("/test.htm");
        mav.addObject("fragmentName", ":: test"); // we'll use this later
        return mav;
    }
}
```

In this case, we can get the following result if we access home index:

```
this is a test fragment
this is a test fragment
```

But if we use a variable `fragmentName` to set th:include value like this:

```html
<div th:fragment="test">
    this is a test fragment
</div>
<div th:include="${fragmentName}"> <!-- modified to use a variable value -->
    this is a placeholder
</div>
```

Thymeleaf complains that this template ":: test" cannot be resolved:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template [:: test], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "/test.htm" - line 5, col 6)
```

Here comes the question: is there a way to set the `th:include` value using a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Thymeleaf expression preprocessing:

```
<div th:include="__${fragmentName}__"> 
    this is a placeholder
</div>
```

Basically you instructed thymeleaf to preprocess first __${fragmentName}__ and after resolving the value to use it in the normal processing phase when evaluates the th:include as if it was a static value th:include=":: test"

Comment: thanks, it works like a charm! appreciate the help again.